# Sort by distance limit

Tags: php, mysql

I present my current concern.

I have a user table with different fields, one of which indicates the distance (in meters) that the user wants to discover other people (example 69587) via a php function that compares the user's user Criteria).

On this side, no worries, but where I block, is that I have to display them page by page. I can not make a query for all (2'000 users for example) then I have to use a LIMIT X, X but suddenly it shows the users one by one (which is of course wanted) but how to attribute the calculated distances between User and members posted to members matching these distances so I can then view the members wanted by the user?

Can I make a fictitious field in the database (I do not know if it is possible), that is to create a field with "distance that separates me from the others" and thus be able to display page by page ?

The worry is that the distance is specific to each user, I do not know how to do or how the other sites (example: dating site).

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Clarification, You want to match users by distance they are willing to travel?
As if i'm 2000km away from you and you are willing to travel 2500km and i'm willing to travel 3000 we'll be a match? Could you reproduce the basic of your SQL in a fiddle please ? http://sqlfiddle.com I suggest you add the sql tag question as they are lots of SQL wizard around here.

Comment: The display depends on a desired distance entered in the database by members

Comment: Because i know there is a way to join a table to itself so you could join your users ON distance=distance but it would only get you those who have identical value.

Comment: I didn't really understand any of that.